# How to define static libraries in separate CMake subdirectories which depend on each others' interfaces and generated headers?

Tags: c++, cmake

Let's say I have a project that creates two static library targets (`foo` and `bar`) with a cyclic dependency between them. CMake explicitly [allows this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#cyclic-dependencies-of-static-libraries) and it normally works fine because the order of building these libraries doesn't matter.

However, if both these libraries generate a header file (`Foo.hpp` for `foo`, `Bar.hpp` for `bar`) that is part of their interface, problems may arise because the generation of the header is usually done as part of building the library (e.g., via [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) and [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html)). That is, building `foo` will generate `Foo.hpp` but also needs `Bar.hpp` which is built by `bar` which needs `Foo.hpp`...

I found a solution to this problem which, on first sight, seems perfect. It consists of generating the headers using [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) and then adding the headers to the `PUBLIC` sources of the target using [`target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html). This way, both a target itself and its dependents will have a file-level dependency on the header which will trigger the custom command at the correct time.

Here's a MWE of my solution:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Foo)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Foo.hpp
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Foo.hpp
    COMMENT "Generating Foo.hpp"
)

add_library(foo STATIC Foo.cpp)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
target_sources(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Foo.hpp)
target_link_libraries(foo bar)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bar.hpp
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bar.hpp
    COMMENT "Generating Bar.hpp"
)

add_library(bar STATIC Bar.cpp)
target_include_directories(bar PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
target_sources(bar PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bar.hpp)
target_link_libraries(bar foo)
```

The problem is that custom commands only work when their output is being referred to from the same directory (this is [documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html)). If I split-up my project and put `foo` and `bar` in different directories, my solution above doesn't work anymore.

So my question is: is there a better way of dealing with cyclic dependencies between the generated headers of static libraries?

Comment: Have you tried to add the header file commands as dependencies (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html)? I would try `add_dependencies(bar ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Foo.hpp)` and `add_dependencies(foo ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bar.hpp); `

Comment: @SimonKraemer: `add_dependencies` only works with top-level targets, not for file-level dependencies. You could first create such a target with `add_custom_target` but then we're back at the problem described in the second paragraph of my question.

Comment: Maybe you could have custom targets `foo_headers` and `bar_headers`, and have `foo` depend on `bar_headers` and viceversa? You could add the produced headers to the library targets with a generator expression or similar, for example for `foo` something like `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:bar_headers,SOURCES>`...

Comment: @jdehesa: That's indeed a possibility but the annoying thing then is that `foo` should know that `bar` has a target for generating headers which is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: @Job Yes I can see that's annoying. Is it unavoidable that the headers are generated during the build step? Afaik, these things are usually done during configuration, e.g. with [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) or simply [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) (I think that's how it's done for example by [`FindProtobuf`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindProtobuf.html)).

Comment: @jdehesa: That's indeed another way of solving the problem. The downside is that *all* code generation is done at configure time then. In my case, the code generator takes quite a long time and is not necessary for all targets (i.e., we building a target that doesn't need generated headers, the CMake configure step will still generate them).

Comment: @Job I see... I think some projects use configuration parameters (`-D` flags) to enable or disable different targets or parts of the build (like "build for Android", etc.), but again that makes for more complicated `CMakeLists.txt` and build system usage...

Answer (score 0):

> If I split-up my project and put foo and bar in different directories, my solution above doesn't work anymore.

What do you mean by splitting them up? You can put the source files of the targets in dedicated subdirectories and still define their targets in the same CMake "subdirectory".

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Foo)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Foo/Foo.hpp"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E touch "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Foo/Foo.hpp"
    COMMENT "Generating Foo.hpp"
    VERBATIM
)

add_library(foo STATIC Foo/Foo.cpp)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
target_sources(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Foo/Foo.hpp)
target_link_libraries(foo bar)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bar/Bar.hpp"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E touch "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bar/Bar.hpp"
    COMMENT "Generating Bar.hpp"
    VERBATIM
)

add_library(bar STATIC Bar/Bar.cpp)
target_include_directories(bar PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
target_sources(bar PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bar/Bar.hpp)
target_link_libraries(bar foo)
```

If you mean that you want to define the targets in those dedicated subdirectories, can't you just do:

```
# :/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Foo)
add_subdirectory(Foo)
add_subdirectory(Bar)

# :/Foo/CMakeLists.txt
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Foo/Foo.hpp"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E touch "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Foo/Foo.hpp"
    COMMENT "Generating Foo.hpp"
    VERBATIM
)
add_library(foo STATIC Foo.cpp)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
target_sources(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Foo/Foo.hpp)
target_link_libraries(foo bar)

# :/Bar/CMakeLists.txt
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bar/Bar.hpp"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E touch "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bar/Bar.hpp"
    COMMENT "Generating Bar.hpp"
    VERBATIM
)
add_library(bar STATIC Bar.cpp)
target_include_directories(bar PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
target_sources(bar PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Bar/Bar.hpp)
target_link_libraries(bar foo)
```

Comment: `Foo.cpp` includes `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Bar/Bar.hpp` which in turn includes the generated file `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Bar/Bar.hpp` (ie: in it's public interface). Similarly, `Bar.cpp` includes `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Foo/Foo.hpp` which in turn includes the generated file `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Foo/Foo.hpp`. When building, cmake starts with `Bar`, generates the `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Bar/Bar.hpp` file, and then includes `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Foo/Foo.hpp`. However, the file generation for Foo hasn't happened yet, so `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Foo/Foo.hpp` doesn't exist yet, and the build fails.

Comment: @SteveLorimer Does the asker's question have source-dir headers with the same name as the generated binary-dir headers? I didn't get that from reading the question post.