# cmake circular dependency with generated files in different directories

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

I have a circular dependency between 2 libraries.

Both libraries have, in their interface, a generated file (a google protobuf object).

When attempting to build, the circular dependency means one of the protobuf files hasn't been generated yet, and the build fails because the protobuf header file doesn't exist.

I have created a small exemplar replicating the behaviour I'm seeing.

Here's an overview of the directory structure:

```
/
+-- CMakeLists.txt        add_subdirectory(foo) & add_subdirectory(bar)
+-- foo/
|   +-- CMakeLists.txt    commands to run protoc on foo.proto & add_library(foo)
|   +-- foo.proto         protoc will generate foo.pb.cc & foo.pb.h
|   +-- foo.h             public interface of lib foo
|   +-- foo.cpp           implementation, includes bar/bar.h
+-- bar/
    +-- CMakeLists.txt    commands to run protoc on foo.proto & add_library(bar)
    +-- bar.proto         protoc will generate bar.pb.cc & bar.pb.h
    +-- bar.h             public interface of lib bar
    +-- bar.cpp           implementation, includes foo/foo.h
```

**Lib 1 - `foo/foo.h`:**

```
#pragma once
#include "foo/foo.pb.h"

struct Bar;

struct Foo
{
    Foo(const cfg::Foo&);

    void add(const Bar&);  // dependency on Bar

    const cfg::Foo cfg;    // the foo protobuf object
};
```

**Lib 2 - `bar/bar.h`:**

```
#pragma once
#include "bar/bar.pb.h"

struct Foo;

struct Bar
{
    Bar(const cfg::Bar&);

    void add(const Foo&);  // dependency on Foo

    const cfg::Bar cfg;    // the bar protobuf object
};
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` for `foo` and `bar` are basically identical.

- use `add_custom_command` to run the protocol buffers compiler
- use `set_source_file_properties` to mark the probuf files as `GENERATED`
- use `add_library` to create the library
- use `target_sources` to add the generated files to the public interface of the library
- use `target_link_libraries` to add the dependency on the other library

```
set(PROTO_SRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.pb.cc)
set(PROTO_HDR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.pb.h)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${PROTO_SRC}
        ${PROTO_HDR}

    COMMAND
        protoc --cpp_out ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.proto -I ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}

    MAIN_DEPENDENCY
        foo.proto
)

set_source_files_properties(${PROTO_SRC} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
set_source_files_properties(${PROTO_HDR} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)

add_library          (foo STATIC foo.cpp)
target_sources       (foo PUBLIC ${PROTO_SRC} ${PROTO_HDR})
target_link_libraries(foo bar)
```

The `bar/CMakeLists.txt` file is identical to the above, just with `s/foo/bar/g` and vice-versa.

The root `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't do much of anything other than `add_subdirectory` `foo` and `bar`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(scratch CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Werror")

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

add_subdirectory(foo)
add_subdirectory(bar)
```

When I attempt to build, `bar` is built first (presumably because I list `add_subdirectory(foo)` first in the main `CMakeLists.txt`, and foo has a dependency on bar via `target_link_libraries`)

When `bar` is built, the protocol buffers compiler hasn't been run for `foo.proto` yet, and so `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/foo/foo.pb.h` doesn't exist yet.

```
In file included from /home/steve.lorimer/src/scratch/bar/bar.cpp:2:
/home/steve.lorimer/src/scratch/foo/foo.h:2:10: fatal error: foo/foo.pb.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "foo/foo.pb.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I *thought* specifying `target_sources` with the generated files, and the fact they have `PROPERTY GENERATED TRUE` would be sufficient to tell cmake the generated files need to be created first, but clearly that's not working.

**Question:**

Is there any way to get cmake to create the generated files *first*, and then run the compilation stage second?

**Notes:**

This SO question, [How to define static libraries in separate CMake subdirectories which depend on each others' interfaces and generated headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233187/how-to-define-static-libraries-in-separate-cmake-subdirectories-which-depend-on) is basically the same thing, but there doesn't seem to be a resolution there.

There are a number of issues on the kitware gitlab which are maybe related?

- [How to solve the circular dependency between the static library and object library](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22149)
- [target_sources() doesn't recognise GENERATED property for sources added from different scope to target](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18399)

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: How about create another project to generate both protobuf, as dependency of your existing project?

Comment: Yes that woukd work, but it's an ugly workaround. These proto files are local to each library, if I could just make cmake generate the files as part of the dependency graph it would solve my problem

Comment: Note: if you know there is an existing question and it is essentially the same, don't ask a new question. Follow the existing one, and optionally, put a bounty on it. Only ask a new question if you think your question [is not a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/997587). If it's not a duplicate, explain clearly why.

Comment: From [the `add_custom_command` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html): "_Each output file will be marked with the GENERATED source file property automatically_".

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you switch to using [the "build events" signature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) of `add_custom_command`? What happens if you switch to using `add_custom_target`? If neither of those work, what about `add_custom_target` + using `add_dependencies` to make foo explicitly depend on the target that generates the bar header?